# По окончании таймера должен проигрываться звук, этого не происходит

Tags: android, mediaplayer

До плеера и после него всё работает нормально, отсутствует только звук.

```
      @Override
                public void onFinish() {


                                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Boui.this, R.raw.sound);
                                    mp.start();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Boui.this, Bee.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Попробуйте класс `SoundPool`, он попроще и понадёжнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохая идея воспроизводить звук в **onFinish()**. Активити закрывается прежде чем звук воспроизведется. Рекомендую в **onCreate** нового активити **Bee.class** добавить:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
```